# VBA + checkboxes + autofilter

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I have a list in excel with an autofilter and where every row has a checkbox.

I have made a button with a macro to select all the checkboxes. This works fine. But when I filter my rows my 'select all' has to **select only the visible checkboxes**.

With my code it still selects all the checkboxes. Has anybody an idea to solve this?

My code:

```
  Sub SelectAll()
  Dim chk As CheckBox

  If Worksheets("Summary").FilterMode = True Then
    MsgBox "Filter mode is on"      
  Else
    MsgBox "Filter mode is off"
    For Each chk In Worksheets("Summary").CheckBoxes
      chk.Value = Checked
    Next
  End If
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking it that your checkboxes are being hidden by the filtering.

This might help, inside your loop:

```
Dim chkRng As Range
Set chkRng = chk.TopLeftCell
Let addr = chkRng.Address ' for debugging to verify the cell the checkbox is associated with
Dim visr As Range
Set visr = chkRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Set ans = Intersect(visr, chkRng)
If Not ans Is Nothing Then
   MsgBox ("visible")
End If
```